# How to put image in sidebar box

Tags: html, windows

I'm relatively new to the whole html scene. I have been working with my companies website (admininsight.com) and I have been trying to put an image in the sidebarbox of the "Medical billing/coding page) http://admininsight.com/medical.html

Here is the code I have been trying:

```
  <div class="grid_9 pull_3"> <img src="../images/medicine.jpg"  alt="medicine" width="250px"  longdesc="images/medicine.jpg" /></div>

      <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

I want the image in the top left of the page (similar to how the testimonials are placed), can anyone help??
 THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work if you just put it in there. You might have an error you markup somewhere. Replace your div with id of "content" with the following:

```
<div class="container_12" id="content">
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="MainContent" -->
    <div class="grid_9 push_3">
        <img alt="senior" longdesc="images/medical-billing.jpg" src="../images/medical-billing.jpg" width="100%">

        <div style="height:30px;"></div><!-- div to space elements -->

        <h2>Medical Coding and Billing Services</h2>

        <p>Our staff has extensive prior experience working for local major medical providers. We know how to properly process receivables using CPT and ICD-9 codes. If these service and diagnostic codes don't match up, it can delay payments and cost a small medical office big money.</p>

        <p>Why take chances? For less than what you would pay an inexperienced part-timer to muddle their way through that paperwork, Administrative Insight can handle all of it - properly and professionally.</p>
    </div><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

    <div style="height:30px;"></div>

    <div class="grid_3 pull_9">
        <img alt="medicine" longdesc="images/medicine.jpg" src="../images/medicine.jpg" width="250px">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```